# How do you connect the dots using the Repository pattern?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I googled too much on this pattern, and I think I am confusing myself, so your input would be greatly appreciated.

If I had a database for my small application, this would portray it:

- Company

  - Name
  - Address
  - TemplateFilePath
- Department

  - Name
  - Address
  - Report Number
- Accident

  - Report Number
  - Location
  - DriverLastNames
  - Date

Basically, I have some code already made up that serializes and deserializes my model objects into JSON, but the code is messy and tightly coupled. I want to basically abstract this, so when I decide to use a DB later, it will be relatively easy to switch as the application grows.

Now if I were to make Repositories (I assume it wouldn't be a single one), what would the method signatures look like? Would I use any interfaces? Here's what I started out doing:

`IRepository<T>`

- `Add(T Entity)`
- `Delete(T Entity)`
- `Update(T Entity)`

`ICustomerRepository : IRepository<Customer>`

- `GetAllCustomers()`
- `GetCustomerByName(string name)`

`IDepartmentRepository : IRepository<Department>`

- `GetAllDepartments()`
- `GetDepartmentByName(string name)`

Then I started thinking, I am not going to be writing DRY code... The customer and department repository is basically doing the same thing, the only difference is the method names and the actual DB table or file the information is being stored in. **Am I doing it right?**

From what I've been reading, a repository is just a wrapper for your actual storage. Like if I were using SQLite, I would be making the connection in the repository, and my regular code would only deal with Customer and Department classes, knowing nothing about how the SQL connections or de/serializing, and only knowing about the Repositories.

Comment: I don't think it's important to share an interface across repositories. It's nifty, but each of my repositories has its own interface - and I use it. Now, if the goal is to *completely automate CRUD* then a single interface may make more sense from the proxy that handles this - but automatic CRUD very quickly seems to break down when wanting to be more expressive ..

Answer (score 0):

Design wise, it looks ok. Keeping very general methods in the base interface (for example, Insert/Delete/Update/GetById) and specialised function in the entity specific interfaces is a fairly standard way of doing it.

DRY wise, I'd say that the important part is that clients do not need to know about anything except the interface, so just make your interfaces as clear to work with as possible. When the interfaces are set, you can choose to DRY up the *repository implementation* totally independent of the clients.

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts :

- `Update()` is generally not handled at the Repository level since you most often want to save changes in a whole graph of entities at once, not just one. One common way of dealing with that is through a Unit of Work at the Application Service / use case level, which might in turn leverage an ORM's change tracker.
- Yes, you'll need interfaces if you want to inject different Repository implementations into their consumers, like mock Repositories in tests for instance.
- Instead of trying to figure out a hierarchy of interfaces up front, what I like to do is take a need-driven approach. In other words, create Repository interfaces as you discover you need them  - it might be in unit tests when you realize you need to talk to a mock Repository, it might be when writing production code. The way client code consumes Repositories will shape your interfaces and you'll be guaranteed that each of these interfaces is really there for a reason.